# How do I rotate a 2D rectangle in Java by pressing keys?

Tags: java, rotation, awt, 2d, keylistener

I am currently attempting to make my first simple java game. I've followed a certain Youtube tutorial up until this point but would like to add my own features, one of which is being able to rotate the player by pressing a certain key. I have been looking up on how to do this for a while now but after numerous failed attempts would be grateful if anyone could suggest how I should do this.

Here is my player class where I have tried rotating the player by implementing a KeyListener:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Player extends GameObject implements KeyListener{

    private Handler handler;
    private HUD hud;
    public float rotation = 0;

    public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler, HUD hud) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
        this.hud = hud;

    }

    public void tick() {

        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        x = Game.clamp(x, 0, Game.WIDTH - 38);
        y = Game.clamp(y, 0, Game.HEIGHT - 67);

        collision();

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);      
        //g.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32);
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.append(r, false);

        AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
        t.rotate(rotation);
        path.transform(t);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(path);

    }


    public void collision() {

        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getId() == ID.BasicEnemy) {
                if (getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                    hud.HEALTH -= 2;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public Rectangle getBounds() {

        return new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
                    rotation = (float) (rotation + 0.1);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   

}
```

Below is some of my remaining code that may be important

Game class:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744439430685015162L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12*9;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;

    public Game() {
        handler = new Handler();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game", this);
        handler.addObject(new Player(200, 200, ID.Player, handler, hud));
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try{
            running = false;
            thread.join();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double delta = 0.0;
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000/amountOfTicks;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now-lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                delta--;
                tick();
            }
            if (running) {
                frames++;
                render();
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void tick() {
        handler.tick();
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();



        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        handler.render(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max) {

        if (var <= min) {
            var = min;
        }

        if (var >= max) {
            var = max;
        }

        return var;

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }



}
```

Window class:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8646632868321067448L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame(title);

        jframe.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        jframe.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.add(game);
        game.start();

    }

}
```

GameObject class:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected int x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected int velX, velY;

    public GameObject(int x, int y, ID id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVelX() {
        return velX;
    }

    public void setVelX(int velX) {
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public int getVelY() {
        return velY;
    }

    public void setVelY(int velY) {
        this.velY = velY;
    }



}
```

Handler class:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Handler {

    LinkedList <GameObject> object = new LinkedList <GameObject>();

    public void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object) {
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object) {
        this.object.remove(object);
    }

    public void addObject(int x, int y, ID basicenemy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

KeyInput class:

```
package topDownGame;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{


    private Handler handler;
    public KeyInput(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                    tempObject.setVelY(-5);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    tempObject.setVelY(5);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                    tempObject.setVelX(-5);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                tempObject.setVelX(5);
                }

            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                tempObject.setVelY(0);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    tempObject.setVelY(0);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                    tempObject.setVelX(0);
                }
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    tempObject.setVelX(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ID enum:

```
package topDownGame;

public enum ID {

    Player();

}
```

Comment: [That's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146965/java-swing-key-input-with-jpanel-added-to-joptionpane/34147249#34147249), [that's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463174/getting-my-sprite-to-face-in-a-certain-direction-based-on-keyboard-input-java/23463387#23463387) - yes, they are rotating images, but the basic approach of "how" it's done is what you'll need

Comment: [`Rectangle` based example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573022/how-to-rotate-a-rectangle-in-java2d/13576009#13576009), [something a little more complex, but using the same concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958932/how-do-i-rotate-objects-images-independently-in-java/31959926#31959926) and [an example which focuses on rotating around the centre of the specified object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627150/rotate-a-moving-shape-around-its-center/47628067#47628067)

Comment: Okay, after a lot of digging and rework - nothing is calling the `keyPressed` method of your `Player` object and since the `GameObject` doesn't have a concept of rotation itself, it's going to be impossible for it to occur

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've dug through the example and the "basic" problem you're having is nothing is calling the `Player`'s `keyPressed/Released` methods - the fact is, nothing should.

The intention is, the "input" should be decoupled from the entities and the entities should update their state based on the current state of the game engine.

So, the first thing I would do is "generalise" the available "input operations" which can occur (and to which the game model can respond)

```
public enum InputAction {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, ROTATE;
}
```

That's it.  These are the inputs that the game supports and the entities can use. They are decoupled from "how" they might occur and just provide a means.

Now, to support this idea, we actually need someway to tell the entities that they should "update", this should be done just before they are rendered, but since we're trying to decouple these operations (so the objects could be updated more often then they are rendered for example), we need to provide a new method that performs this operation...

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    //...
    public void update() {
    }
    //...
}
```

*(nb: technically this method could be `abstract`, as almost all the entities are doing to need to change in someway, but for simplicity, I've just made it a empty implementation)*

Next, we need some way for the entities to respond to these input actions and some way to manage them, in your case the `Handler` is probably the best choice, as it provides a link between the entities and the other aspects of the system (like rendering and input control)

```
public class Handler {
    //...
    private Set<InputAction> inputActions = new HashSet<InputAction>();

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.update();
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean is(InputAction action) {
        return inputActions.contains(action);
    }

    public void set(InputAction action) {
        inputActions.add(action);
    }

    public void remove(InputAction action) {
        inputActions.remove(action);
    }
    //...

}
```

Okay, now the "input mechanism" can tell the `Handler` when the state has changed, based on it's implementation...

```
public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

    private Handler handler;

    public KeyInput(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            handler.set(InputAction.UP);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            handler.set(InputAction.DOWN);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            handler.set(InputAction.LEFT);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            handler.set(InputAction.RIGHT);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            handler.set(InputAction.ROTATE);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            handler.remove(InputAction.UP);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            handler.remove(InputAction.DOWN);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            handler.remove(InputAction.LEFT);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            handler.remove(InputAction.RIGHT);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            handler.remove(InputAction.ROTATE);
        }
    }

}
```

*(Yes, they could be `if-else if` statements, but I'm just modifying the existing code for brevity)*

And finally, we need to update the `Player` object so it can "update" it's state based on the current "state" of the game engine...

```
public class Player extends GameObject {

    private Handler handler;
    public float rotation = 0;

    public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {//, HUD hud) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;

    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        if (handler.is(InputAction.UP)) {
            setVelY(-5);
        } else if (handler.is(InputAction.DOWN)) {
            setVelY(5);
        } else {
            setVelY(0);
        }

        if (handler.is(InputAction.LEFT)) {
            setVelX(-5);
        } else if (handler.is(InputAction.RIGHT)) {
            setVelX(5);
        } else {
            setVelX(0);
        }

        if (handler.is(InputAction.ROTATE)) {
            rotation += 0.1;
        }
    }

    public void tick() {

        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        x = Game.clamp(x, 0, Game.WIDTH - 38);
        y = Game.clamp(y, 0, Game.HEIGHT - 67);

        collision();

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);      
        //g.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32);
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.append(r, false);

        AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
        t.translate(x, y);
        t.rotate(rotation, 16, 16);
        path.transform(t);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(path);
        g2d.dispose();

    }

    public void collision() {

        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

//              if (tempObject.getId() == ID.BasicEnemy) {
//                  if (getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
//                      hud.HEALTH -= 2;
//                  }
//              }
        }

    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32);
    }

}
```

I want to take a closer look at the `render` method, as it's a little more complicated...

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    // 1...
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    // 2...
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32);
    Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
    path.append(r, false);

    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
    // 3...
    t.translate(x, y);
    // 4...
    t.rotate(rotation, 16, 16);
    path.transform(t);
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.draw(path);
    // 5...
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Okay:

1. `Graphics` is a shard concept, that means that EVERY entity that needs to be painted will get the same `Graphics` context, including any and all changes which have been made to it by previous entities.  This "might" be desirable, but in general, you want to reduce the amount of "side effects" which might occur.  So, we create a new copy of it first.
2. We create the `Rectangle`.  Oddly, this is (now) a bad place to do it here, because it's state actually never changes.  The `Rectangle` is always created at position `0x0` and has a size of `32x32` ... but wait, I want it to move and do stuff!  I know, you will see "how" in ...
3. We translate the origin of the `Graphics` context to the position of the player ... this now makes the `0x0` position, the same as the players position . This is a neat cheat and means, as I stated above, you no longer need to create a `Rectangle` EVERY time `render` is called, which will further improve performance
4. We rotate the `Graphics` context around the centre point of the object (the object been `32x32` makes the centre point `16x16` - remember, the origin point is `0x0` ... do you see why that little change is SO important and useful )
5. We `dispose` of the copy.  This just releases any resources held by this copy, the action we've taken are still applied back to the original, but don't affect any operations which might occur after (so the origin point and rotation are the same as they were when `render` was first called).

## Observations...

While working my way through the code, it become clear that the code was not well organised.  One thing that really annoyed me was the fact that `Game` would create an instance of `Window` in order to display itself - this is actually a side effect and something that `Game` shouldn't be doing (it shouldn't care).

So, I took your `main` method and wrangled it to be...

```
public static void main(String args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Game");

            Game game = new Game();
            jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jframe.add(game);
            jframe.pack();
            jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jframe.setVisible(true);
            game.start();
        }
    });
}
```

So, a number of small changes...

- The instance of `game` is added to the frame almost straight away (this is important for another change I made)
- The frame is "packed" around the component
- The frame's location is set (so it appears in the middle of the screen), this is done AFTER packing the window, because the size of the frame isn't set until we pack it.
- The frame is made visible - this stops the window from "jumping" to the centre of the screen

I also added...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
```

to `Game`, this provides sizing hints to the container that `Game` is added to.  It also means that when the `JFrame` is `pack`ed, the window will slightly larger then the content area, as the frame's borders are wrapped around it.

I would also recommend taking a look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it has an example of "how" it should be used.

To that end, I modified you `render` method accordingly...

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    do {
        do {
            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            handler.render(g);
            g.dispose();
        } while (bs.contentsRestored());
        bs.show();
    } while (bs.contentsLost());
}
```

One significant change I did make was `g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` - now it will fill the "actual" size of the component, not just the "desired" size ... I'm one of those people who hate (passionately) non-resizable windows ;)

If you're interested in seeing a slightly more complex solution, you could take a [look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612426/how-to-draw-an-image-over-a-background-image/50613543#50613543) which presents a more "generic" and "decoupled" concept

Comment: Oh wow, this was incredibly helpful. Not only did you provide a detailed solution to the main problem I had been facing, but you also added new ways in which I could improve my code. For that, I am eternally grateful. I am able to rotate the rectangle now, and I'll be sure to follow your advice in the future. Thank you so much :)